# Clear Cache in WebAuthenticator Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, caching, xamarin.forms, webauthenticator

I am trying to clear cache for Webpage opened in WebAuthenticator in Xamarin forms. Currently there is a way to open WebAuthenticator in InCognito mode but that can't be used in my case because i need to logout also.

One manual solution is to clear cache manually from device browser.

Is there any way to clear cache programmatically from Xamarin forms while launching?

Comment: Have you checked thread:  [Xamarin Forms Delete Web Cache / Javascript Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54464583/xamarin-forms-delete-web-cache-javascript-storage) ?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I checked that thread, both problem and solution is for **WebView** not for **WebAuthenticator** in Xamarin Forms.